# Finding duplicate stings in rows

Tags: pandas

I was expecting to get the duplicates when I tried this code...

```
import pandas as pd

restaurants = pd.read_csv('restaurants/data.tsv', sep='\t', index_col='id')

restaurants['real_id'] = find_partitions(
    df=restaurants,
    match_func=same_restaurant
)
```

I got same ID (-1) in "real_id" column for each row and not the records as shown in this example:

https://maxhalford.github.io/blog/transitive-duplicates/

I did not get any error so do not know how to troubleshoot.

Comment: post a testable fragment of your `'restaurants/data.tsv'`

Comment: https://github.com/shantanuo/stack_question/blob/master/transitive-duplicates.ipynb

Comment: Both blog post script and your notebook work properly on my side. Can you share the version of `pandas` and `fuzzywuzzy` you're using ?

Comment: fuzzywuzzy (0.18) and pandas (1.3.5)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried solving the fuzzy join via a distance measure like levenshtein?

You could do the following:

```
!pip install textdistance

from textdistance import levenshtein

restaurants['mergecol'] = restaurants['name'] + restaurants['address'] + restaurants['city'] + restaurants['phone'] + restaurants['type']
restaurants['dummy'] = 1

restaurants.dropna(subset='mergecol', inplace=True)
df = pd.merge(restaurants.reset_index()[['id', 'mergecol', 'dummy']], restaurants.reset_index()[['id', 'mergecol', 'dummy']], on='dummy')

df['distance'] = df.apply(lambda x: levenshtein(x['mergecol_x'], x['mergecol_y']), axis=1)
```

Afterwards you can filter the `df` to distances e.g. lower than 20 giving you a list of duplicate pairs.

Note: The code is not very optimal in terms of performance, but gets the job done in this example.

EDIT:
To answer your question: I printed your same_restaurant function output to debug it and found it always returns False. Then I went deeper and found, that your same_area_code function is broken with the data. You split at space, but there is no space in column phone. I would suggest to split at none-number characters like so:

```
import re
def same_area_code(r1, r2):
    return re.split(r'\D+',r1['phone'])[0] == re.split(r'\D+',r2['phone'])[0]
```

This returns some duplicates:
[image]

Comment: Thanks. I will try that module. But the question is why the script mentioned in that blog post does not work?

Comment: @shantanuo, I updated my answer to answer your question.

Answer (score -1):

If I understand your case correctly, we can try the following:

Simplified data:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'address': ['435 s la cienega blv', '435 s la cienega blv', '12224 ventura blvd', '12224 ventura blvd', '701 stone canyon rd', '435 s la cienega blv'],
    'city': ['los angeles', 'los angeles', 'studio city', 'studio city', 'bel air', 'studio city'],
    'type': ['american', 'american', 'delis', 'delis', 'steakhouses', 'american']
})

df
```

Output:

[image]

Then:

```
df = df[df.duplicated(keep=False) == True]
df
```

Output:

[image]